# Json array with repeating tag

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following json:

```
{
  "OBECT_TAG":
  [
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    },
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    },
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the `OBJECT_TAG` to be repeated for each object in array. I tried this and deserialization in c# fails. Is it json compliant or what would make it compliant?

```
{
  [
    "OBECT_TAG":
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    },
    "OBECT_TAG":
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    },
    "OBECT_TAG":
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    }
  ]
}
```

The reason for this, if necessary, is that the objects get quite large with many levels so when manually editing to be easy to identify where each main object starts while keeping it an array and easy c# object deserialization.

Edit: Is important to keep the root object

Comment: But that would make it invalid json.

Comment: @Evk: Yes. That would. Is there a way to achieve this or something similar while keeping it compliant?

Comment: For example you can do: `[ { "OBECT_TAG": {"PROPERTY1" : "value1", "PROPERTY2" : "value2" } }, ... ]`

Comment: @Evk: I think could be a quite good solution. can still keep the root object? `{ [ {""OBECT_TAG": {...}} , {..} ]}`?

Comment: Yes sure. You can nest arrays and objects any way you like. But example from your question is invalid, because inside array there are not objects (`{ ... }`) but some unsupported constructs.

Comment: Well, I have tried and throws exception if a root object is added

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. You need to add a property name if you want to do it like that: `{ "MyArray": [ ... ] }`. Object has properties with names and values `{ "Name" : <value here>}`. Array contains objects or other arrays (or primitive values like strings\numbers).

Comment: Thanks. I think you should post your answer because it is very close to what I want so few probabilities there would be another better.

Comment: @dbc but OP has array with "named" objects, not object with duplicate properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json object has properties with names and values, where value can be another object\array\primitive value.

Json array contains other objects\arrays\primitives without names.

Json from your question violates both of the above.

```
{
  [...]
}
```

Is invalid, because there is no property name. If you want to put array inside object, you have to name it:

```
{
    "MyArray": [...]
}
```

Then

```
[
    "OBECT_TAG":
    {
      "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
      "PROPERTY2" : "value2",
    }
]
```

Is invalid, because array is just a list of unnamed values, and you try to name its entries.

Closest to what you want I can think of is array of objects, where each object contains named property with tag, and that tag object contains properties:

```
[
    { "OBECT_TAG":
      {
        "PROPERTY1" : "value1",
        "PROPERTY2" : "value2"
      }
    }
]
```